# Laravel multi authetification with different users tables

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to build a multiple authentification in laravel with different tables (2 tables) for admin and user. The problème is that the registration and login forms work only with default auth login/register.

I've tried some examples form web tutorials but it didn't work.

HomeController.php:

```php
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index() {
    return view('home');
}
```

I have added createAdmin function in "Auth/RegisterController.php":

```php
protected function createAdmin(array $data)
{
    $this->validator($data->all())->validate();
    $admin = Admin::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    return redirect()->intended('login/admin');
}
```

I have changed email validation rules to:

```php
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'|'unique:admins']
```

And the route (web.php) is:

```php
Route::post('/register/admin', 'Auth\RegisterController@createAdmin');
```

When I fill admin register credentials and click register button I get this message:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::createAdmin(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the `array $data` parameter in your `createAdmin()` controller method.

Usually, you want to use one of two types of parameters in your controller methods: [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-parameters) or [injected dependencies](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers). The `$data` parameter isn't matching either of those, so Laravel doesn't know to provide it.

If you'd like to access the request (POST) data in the controller, you can either ask for an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` as a parameter:

```php
// Import it at the top of your PHP file
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// Then your updated method:
public function createAdmin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    // ...
}
```

Or, use the `request()` helper directly:

```php
public function createAdmin()
{
    $data = request()->all();

    // ...
}
```